# Is it possible to use Jquery validation Framework for capthcha mismatch?

Tags: jquery

In my Application i am using Jquery validation framework for my form to validate before user submits .
This framwork is great , and everything is working fine .

I have a requirement such as :

In my form there is a capthcha field , and if this filed is entrered wrong , instead of an alert how can i show the  message saying capthca mismatch Error ??

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/2yXsL/370/

And this is my code

```
  function callformsubmit()
{

    var validatecpathca = ValidCaptcha();

    if(!validatecpathca)
    {
        alert('Capthcha mismatch');
         DrawCaptcha();
    $('#loginCaptchaCode').val('');
    }
    else
    {
        // do form submit here 
    }

}
```

I just need to  display a message Capthca mismatch beside the **capthcha Mismatch**